# Algolia's xml's "attribute" sparks a compilation error

Tags: android, xml, algolia

I'm trying to implement Algolia using their results UI and following their guide.

I've put in my app's build.gradle `dataBinding.enabled true` as follows

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    dataBinding.enabled true
    ......
```

and in my single hit's layout, I only have one TextView, and I try to binf it by the instructions as follows, but it throws a compilation error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
        xmlns:algolia="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/algolia_question_title"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:text="Not able to succefully rum npm install comand on git bash"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="@color/gray900"
                algolia:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                algolia:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                algolia:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                algolia:attribute='@{"title"}'/>
        <View
                android:id="@+id/divider4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
                algolia:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/algolia_question_title"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

If I remove this line `algolia:attribute='@{"title"}'` it compiles just fine. What am I dong wrong?

EDIT: I was able to find an error message that says the following:
`Cannot find the setter for attribute 'algolia:attribute' with parameter type java.lang.String on android.widget.TextView.file:C\`

There might be more to the message, but it appears only when I hover over a certain error line and continues till the end of my screen, so I can't tell if there's more or not as I am not familiar with this message.

Comment: Are you using databinding in general?  That's a databinding command, it won't work if you aren't..  Also, you need to be using " on the outside, not '.

Comment: @GabeSechan what do you mean if I use it in general? I haven't up till now, but followed the only step they suggested in the documentation which is adding what I've mentioned in my question to the build.gradle. Regarding the `"` vs `'`, this is how they show it in their documentation too, and if I try to change it to `"` then the xml doesn't "except" it

Comment: This is the dcumentation I'm looking at, still can't figure it out.. https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/getting-started/android/

It actually says `Beware of the data binding attributes’ syntax: '@{"string"}'` but I'm not sure what they mean

Comment: Please don't tell us that something "sparks an error" without telling us what the error is.

Comment: @MichaelKay I've literally just finished editing my question to includethe error, but it wasn't easy to find. The inspector didn't find it for me either and all I so was `compilation error`. Might be easier to find for a more advanced programmer but it wasn't in the usual channels I got used to finding it so far.

Comment: @Tsabary I mean if you aren't using databinding and don't have your app set up to use it, that line probably won't work at all.

Comment: @GabeSechan I want to use data binding. If this line would work then as far as I get from the documentation the data binding should work with Algolia's instant search. But it is currently that line that is the only obstacle as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was added after adding this implementation

```
implementation 'com.algolia:instantsearch-androidx:1.15.2'
```